# How to find out the words begin with vowels in a list?

Tags: python, list, search

```
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'milk', 'otter', 'snake', 'iguana',
         'tiger', 'eagle']
vowel=[]
for vowel in words:
    if vowel [0]=='a,e':
        words.append(vowel)
    print (words)
```

My code doesn't right, and it will print out all the words in the original list.

Comment: Problems: 1. You override `vowel` with the loop variable. 2. You append `vowel` to the list you loop over.

Comment: `vowel[0] == 'a,e'` will never be True.  You are comparing a one character string to a three character string.  You want something like `vowel[0] in 'ae'`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'milk', 'otter', 'snake','iguana','tiger','eagle']
for word in words:
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        print(word)
```

You can also use a list comprehension like this

```
words_starting_with_vowel = [word for word in words if word[0] in 'aeiou']
```

Answer (score 9):

Good python reads almost like natural language:

```
vowel = 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'
words = 'apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'milk', 'otter', 'snake', 'iguana', 'tiger', 'eagle'
print [w for w in words if w.startswith(vowel)]
```

The problem with `w[0]` solution is that it doesn't work with empty words (doesn't matter in this particular example, but important in real-life tasks like parsing user input).

Comment: +1 for `.startswith`, but you should add the explanation for the beginner that the first line is only more lazy way to write a tuple, and that the `.startswith` accepts tuples only from Python 2.5. (I know that 2.5 is the Middle Ages, but some people still use the older.)

Comment: +1 didn't notice `.startswith` could accept a tuple like that

Answer (score 7):

Here is a one-liner answer with list comprehension:

```
>>> print [w for w in words if w[0] in 'aeiou']
['apple', 'orange', 'otter', 'iguana', 'eagle']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if vowel [0]=='a,e':
        words.append(vowel)
```

You are appending it to the original list here. It should be your `vowel` list.

```
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'milk', 'otter', 'snake','iguana','tiger','eagle']
vowel=[]
for word in words:
    if word[0] in "aeiou":
        vowel.append(word)
print (vowel)
```

Using List comprehension

```
vowel = [word for word in words if word[0] in "aeiou"]
```

Using `filter`

```
vowel = filter(lambda x : x[0] in "aeiou",words)
```

Comment: sorry, i accidentally voted down. You helped a lot. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

````
res = [] 
list_vowel = "aeiou"
for sub in words: 
   flag = False
   
   # checking for begin char 
   for ele in list_vowel: 
       if sub.startswith(ele): 
           flag = True
           break
   if flag: 
       res.append(sub) 

# printing result 
list_vowel = str(res)
print(list_vowel)```
````

Comment: Output ['apple', 'orange', 'otter', 'iguana', 'eagle']

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
input_list = ['wood','oil','apple','bat','iron','Apple2']

list_vowel = [i for i in input_list if i[0] in "aeiouAEIOU"]

print(list_vowel)
```

or can use

```py
list1 = []

for i in input_list:

    if i[0] in "aeiouAEIOU":

      list1.append(i)

print(list1)
```