# find number of vowels in a string

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have a string of letters as input.
**input:**

```
my_str = 'soumendra_in_stackoverflow'
```

I want output like below. Where all the vowels should be printed along with their corresponding count in a dictionary.
**output needed**:

```
{'a': 2, 'e': 2, 'i': 1, 'o': 3, 'u': 1}
```

For this I have written the following program:

```
ans_dict = {}
for letter in my_str:
    if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        ans_dict[letter] = ans_dict.get(letter, 0) + 1
print(ans_dict)
```

It works. However, how to write this same logic in a single line (maybe using dictionary comprehension) without using `collections.Counter`?
I have tried this but it's failing.

```
{x: + 1 for x in a if x in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] }
```

Comment: Why not using a `Counter`? Looks like the best tool for it. You *can* do it with dictionary comprehension, but as a result you will iterate over the string *five* times, making it *less* efficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833512/how-to-find-out-the-words-begin-with-vowels-in-a-list See first and second answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833512/how-to-find-out-the-words-begin-with-vowels-in-a-list See first and second answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833512/how-to-find-out-the-words-begin-with-vowels-in-a-list

Comment: @Gozzah: I think the linked questions solve a different problem: here we are interested in the *number* of vowels in the string, not the strings (!) in a list that start with a vowel. Yes, there is some overlap, but the two are "different" problems in the strict sense.

Comment: I believe if you use a set for the lookup with the `in` operator, it is faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `str.count` and thus write the dictionary comprehension with:

```
result = { v: my_str.count(v) for v in "aeiou" }
```

But this thus results in enumerating over the `my_str` *five* times. Like @DSM however says, `.count(..)` typically works rather fast (my guess is that it is implemented at the interpreter level, so it does not have to "iterate" over the collection).

Personally I think that a `Counter` here would be better, since

1. it is designed exactly for the purpose of counting things, and furthermore it wraps data into an interface that will enforce constraints (unless there is a bug in the `Counter`, the counts will definitely be correct, whereas a custom made algorithm can still have a "silly" mistake, yes here that is very unlikely, but it is still better to avoid that); and
2. it provides an nice interface to do all sorts of things with these counts (for example `counter1 & counter2` will construct a new `Counter`, with the *minimum* counts of every element).

Comment: Note that "five" might be the wrong thing to stress; count is so fast that at small numbers of keys it's actually more efficient to use `count`.  At only five, it's about an order of magnitude faster on long strings.  The conceptual arguments are stronger (although even there they get murky in the limit -- we'd all write `some_str.count(",")`, not `Counter(some_str)[","]`, for example.)

Comment: @DSM: I think `.count(..)` is indeed faster since it is implemented at the *interpreter* level (well the definition of a Python string). But I do not really like "iterating multiple times" over a collection if we do not have to :). In terms of "big oh" it will scale as *O(m n)* so that means if the number of characters we have to count is rather large (for example all Chinese unicode characters), it will result in a bottleneck. But you are correct that for vowels, this might be faster, or with an insignifant difference).