# How to sort list only with name that starts with vowels?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that asks the user for a list of names and then outputs the names in alphabetical order,  but only if the name starts with a vowel. Please help me to do this,i can do it with only one letter, but it doesn't work with all vowels
Should look like this`
input:
john armin billie olivia eric
output:
['armin', 'eric', 'olivia']

```
lst1 = [str(item) for item in input("Enter names separated by space  : ").split()]


print("The original list : " + str(lst1))

check = "aouie"
for i in lst1:
   if i[0].lower() == check.lower():
       lst1.sort()
print("The list of letter : " + lst1)
```

Comment: Please add the expected output, to make the question more understandable

Comment: if i[0].lower() == check.lower(): Is it ever going to be True that a single character is equal to AOUIE in lowercase?

Comment: If you want to use lower case, why not simply start with `check = 'aouie'` rather than start with upper case and then convert to lower case? In any event, you probably want `i[0].lower() in check.lower()` rather than `i[0].lower() == check.lower()`.

Comment: It is not working as for the input you are taking char by chat but for check, you are comparing it will multiple values stored in check variable. As per current code if user entered Apple then you are comparing `A == AOUIE` which will always fail.

Comment: What should happen to names starting with consonant?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833512/how-to-find-out-the-words-begin-with-vowels-in-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` to check if the name starts with any of the vowels.

```
vowel_names = [name for name in lst1 if name[0].lower() in "aeiou"]
print(sorted(vowel_names))
```

Comment: you missed the "y"

Comment: @KarolMilewczyk "y' is ambiguous, although when it is a first letter it would be functioning as a consonant (at least I can't think of any counterexample).